# Rendering Specific Value from State Array in React.js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am creating an online scorecard application for a 9-hole golf course using React.js, State, and rendering.  A user enters his or her score for each hole, which 'pushes' hole number & hole score to an array (known as golferOneScore) in the State.  Rendering to the browser is proving difficult, though, for display of each hole's score in attempting to render via map method based on value of hole in the array...

I've tried mapping out the array (specifically for one hole number) in my html area.  It works, but doing so, though, is limiting display to only one hole per map.  Upon time to map for the score on hole 2, I'm losing display of my entry in the browser for hole 1.

```
{this.state.golferOneScore.map((data) =>  {
    if (data.hole == 1) { 
        return (<tr><td>golferOne</td><td>{data.score}</td></tr>)
        })};
```

Expecting to display in  all 9 holes of scores accurately, even if a golfer should, for any reason, skip a hole.

Comment: I've also tried to just side-step the mapping process altogether with something like:

<td>{this.state.golferOneScore.hole["1"].score}</td>

the only problem is the array isn't populated yet, so the site breaks and says the array is empty...would much prefer this route, but not working, either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned I could simply use a find method for each hole golfed

```
{this.state.nameOneScore.find(scores => scores.hole === '1').score}
```

ternary condition to control for null is important, too.